# Creating a Delay in C

Tags: c

I am new to programming. I have been trying to figure out a time delay to slow down the execution of my program. I have been doing research and can not find one that works I have read about `nanosleep` and `sleep` I have tried both but when I put them in the `for` loop it waits a few seconds and then executes the entire `for` loop without pausing between iterations. Maybe I have an error in my code? I have included it below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
   int main(void)
   {
      FILE *fp;
      int i;

      /* open the file */
      fp = fopen("/dev/pi-blaster", "w");
      if (fp == NULL) {
         printf("I couldn't open pi-blaster for writing.\n");
         exit(0);
      }

      /* write to the file */
    for(i=99;i>=0;i--){
      sleep(1);
      fprintf(fp, "0=0.%d\n",i);
    }
      /* close the file */
      fclose(fp);

      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: OS caching, most likely. What makes you sure few-byte writes will be visible immediately?

Comment: Try an fflush() after your print.

Comment: Are you using _this_ pi_blaster? https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster/

Comment: @JanDvorak yes that is the pi_blaster

Comment: Note that `/dev/pi-blaster` is actually a FIFO, not a device.

Comment: @duskwuff which doesn't prevent application-level caching

Comment: @JanDvorak: Right -- just threw me for a loop, is all.

Comment: About `fopen`: [`The returned stream is fully buffered by default if it is known to not refer to an interactive device`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/). No idea how "known to not refer to an interactive device" is defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writes to your file `fp` are being buffered.  `fflush(fp)` inside the for loop so it writes data out to the file before the next iteration.  Otherwise, it'll write a line to the buffer, sleep a second, write to the buffer, sleep a second, etc, and then flush the buffer to the file either when the buffer fills up or when `fclose(fp)` is called.  `man fflush` for more details.

Comment: About `fopen`: [`The returned stream is fully buffered by default if it is known to not refer to an interactive device`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/). No idea how "known to not refer to an interactive device" is defined

Comment: I think an "interactive device" is a tty or similar.  I wouldn't think that a FIFO would qualify as an interactive device.

Comment: In Java there is a separate `BufferedInputStream`/`BufferedOutputStream` that can be stuffed to any other `InputStream`/`OutputStream` and is commonly recommended to wrap every `FileInputStream`/`FileOutputStream`. In other words, it's entirely up to the application to request buffering.

Comment: hm, do you get no OS-level buffering on Java file writes by default without wrapping in a Buffered stream?  That'd be surprising.